# Media Player Fullscreen in Recyclerview

Tags: android, scroll, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview, android-fullscreen

I have a recyclerview in it I have media players.  I want to make them full screen on a button click.  I have tried two methods to implement this.

1. Create a new intent and pass the video details to the new intent (current position and url).  However this caused a lot of issues with the Media Player state machine.
2. Get the screen dimensions and expand the view to the size of the screen.  The problem with this is that the recyclerview is still scrollable..  I did create a touch listener to intercept the touch event, however also disabled touch events on the recycler item.

The second options works a little better than the first except for a. the scrolling of the recycler view and b. hiding and showing the status bar as when it is shown again after hiding along with the tool bar it overlays the toolbar.

This is the code I use to set to full screen and to hide the toolbar/notification bar.

```
 DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        application.getCurrentActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        application.getCurrentActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        application.getCurrentActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

   layoutParams.height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            layoutParams.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

 mTextureView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and to return I use this code to show the toolbar and notification bar..

```
main.getSupportActionBar().show();
           main.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

So I am trying to temporarily disable scrolling on the recycler view without preventing touch events to the items.

Also to try to prevent the overlay of the status bar over the tool bar.

If anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the layoutmanager of your recycleview for this. This way it will only disable only scrolling. You will still be able to handle click or any other touch event. For example:-

```
public class CustomGridLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
private boolean isScrollEnabled = true;

public CustomGridLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollVertically() {
   //Similarly you can customize "canScrollHorizontally()" for managing horizontal scroll
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollVertically();
}
}
```

Here using "isScrollEnabled" flag you can enable/disable scrolling functionality of your recycle-view temporarily.